# Compare list if it's in SQL table Column

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, console, sql-server-express

I have a console application that is scraping data from a website, this is the scraping part:

```
private static void getPageThumbLinks()
{
    thumbUrlsList = new List<string>();
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36";
    foreach (string value in pageLinks)
    {

        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.example.com/" + value);
        foreach (HtmlNode nodes in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='searchResultsSmallThumbnail']/a"))
        {
            HtmlAttribute href = nodes.Attributes["href"];
            var hreflink = href.Value;
            thumbUrlsList.Add(hreflink);
            //Console.WriteLine(hreflink);
        }
        compareToSql();
    }
}
```

I have list with a collection of URLs, `thumbUrlsList` and an MSSQL Express table named `Table` with a Column named `link`.

Is it possible to compare this list with the databases `link` column and check if it exists or not?

If so if, can you give me an example?
It will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Do you have examples of the items in the `pageLinks` and in the database (link column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a list of link that already exist in the database is dbList.

```
var dbList = new List<string>() { "Dave", "Steve", "Pete" };
```

and your new thumbList

```
var thumbList = new List<string>() { "Dave", "Steve", "Pete", "Paul", "Mike" };
```

Now to get url list that does not exist in database use this

```
var newLinkList = thumbList.Except(dbList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick example. You can use LINQ to check if it exists.

```
private static void getPageThumbLinks()
{
    thumbUrlsList = new List<string>();
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36";
    foreach (string value in pageLinks)
    {

        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.example.com/" + value);
        foreach (HtmlNode nodes in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='searchResultsSmallThumbnail']/a"))
        {
            HtmlAttribute href = nodes.Attributes["href"];
            var hreflink = href.Value;
            thumbUrlsList.Add(hreflink);
            //Console.WriteLine(hreflink);

            // Here is where you check if the DataTable has the link
            // Table is a DataTable containing the results of your query
            var containsLink = Table.AsEnumerable().Any(row => link == row.Field<string>("link"));

            if (containsLink) 
            {
                // do something with it
            }
        }
    }
}
```